# Can't compile boost 1.50.0 under Cygwin on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: boost, compiler-errors, cygwin, windows-7-x64

I am trying to compile boost 1.50.0 under Cygwin on Windows 7 64-bit.

I run the command:

```
./bootstrap.sh –prefix=boost/
```

and I get back:

```
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc...
Failed to build Boost.Build build engine
Consult 'bootstrap.log' for more details
```

Here is the log:

```
###
### Using 'gcc' toolset.
###
rm -rf bootstrap
mkdir bootstrap
gcc -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c function.c glob.c         hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathunix.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c pwd.c class.c native.c md5.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execunix.c fileunix.c
function.c: In function ‘var_edit_shift’:
function.c:653:13: warning: ‘cygwin_conv_to_win32_path’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sys/cygwin.h:36) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
./bootstrap/jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=gcc --toolset-root= clean
./build.sh: line 13:  8144 Segmentation fault      $@
```

What could be the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Don't know if you can build the binary libs yet (normally most of boost are header only, you only have to build some libs manually). However in my experience it's so complicated to build/use Boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes it evident that the `cygwin_conv_to_win32_path` is deprecated.

> function.c:653:13: warning: ‘cygwin_conv_to_win32_path’ is deprecated
>   (declared at /usr/include/sys/cygwin.h:36) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

**History**:
The function `cygwin_conv_to_win32_path` was supported in Cygwin 1.x and was deprecated in 2.x versions. The 2.x provides the  replacement API `cygwin_conv_path`

**How to fix it?**
Add definition for these deprecated methods as below, and it should resolve the issue( I did the same and was able to build boost library on cygwin)

```
void cygwin_conv_to_win32_path(const char *posix, char * win32)
{
    /* Get the size */
    ssize_t size = cygwin_conv_path( CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_A, posix, NULL, 0);
    cygwin_conv_path( CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_A, posix, win32, size);
}

void cygwin_conv_to_posix_path (const char *win32, char * posix)
{
    /* Get the size */
    ssize_t size = cygwin_conv_path( CCP_WIN_A_TO_POSIX, win32, NULL, 0);
    cygwin_conv_path(  CCP_WIN_A_TO_POSIX , win32, posix, size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`boost` is not a simple package to build, and also requires a number of buildsystem and code patches to build and work correctly.  (See [Cygwin Ports git](http://cygwin-ports.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-ports/boost;a=tree) for details.)  I strongly suggest you use the `libboost-devel` package in the Cygwin distribution instead.